# Variables in java are copied or referenced

Tags: android, virtualization

```
  private static Virtualizer createVirtualizer()
  {
      try
      {
          if (virtualizer == null)
          {
              Virtualizer localVirtualizer1 = new Virtualizer(0, 0);
              virtualizer = localVirtualizer1;
              localVirtualizer1.setEnabled(true);
          }
          Virtualizer localVirtualizer2 = virtualizer;
          return localVirtualizer2;
     }
      finally {}
  }
```

I am modifying someone's code. I think `localVirtualizer` is not neccessary for this code. And the main thing why am i here. if i `initialize` object in `java`. Are they refer to same location. As you see after initializing

```
virtualizer = localVirtualizer1;
```

he set enable `localVirtualizer1.setEnabled(true);`

it means virtualizer is also enable. Am i having the right concept?

If they are referencing then both of them are enabled otherwise virtualizer is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on variable you are trying to pass. For example, int variable are passed by value and array/list are by reference. In short, all objects are passed by reference and normal variables/datatypes are not.

In your code, I see you are calling static method. So, in your scenario there is only one object and it is referred.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got it right. Objects in Java are always passed by reference (and non-objects, like `int, float, double` are passed by value). So both virtualizer and localVirtualizer1 refer to the same object in the memory. They are just different aliases of the same object. Hence, changing one would update the other as well.

Comment: And i can also remove localVirtualizer1 . it is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, you can do the update directly on the virtualizer object.